# Insertar desde archivo CSV a tabla in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

He intentado sin éxito ingresar desde un archivo CSV a mi tabla de datos.
Hasta ahora el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile files)
    {

        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        if (files.Length > 0)
        {


            var st = new MemoryStream();
            await files.CopyToAsync(st);
            //files.CopyTo(st);
            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(st.ToArray());                

            return Ok(content);

        }
        else
        {
            return Ok("ERROR");
        }



    }
```

Si bien me muestra los resultado con el return no logro avanzar para insertar cada registro en mi tabla de datos. 
Alguna ayuda?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si bien pude insertar los registros del archivo CSV, solamente lo hace a partir de la segunda fila. Probé dejando una sola fila y me aparece una excepción que el formato no es válido para el campo a insertar. (aclaro que este error no me aparece cuando hay mas de un registro. Inserta bien, pero desde la segunda fila de mi archivo CSV). Paso el código:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile files, Opj opj)
    {
        //long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

        // full path to file in temp location
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        if (files.Length > 0)
        {


            var st = new MemoryStream();
            await files.CopyToAsync(st);
            //files.CopyTo(st);
            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(st.ToArray());
            string[] datos = content.Split("\n");

            foreach(var item in datos)
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
                {
                    var cells = item.Split(";");
                    opj.NroOrden = Convert.ToInt32(cells[0]);
                    opj.Abogado = cells[1];
                    opj.Caratula = cells[2];
                    opj.Dni = Convert.ToInt32(cells[3]);
                    opj.Importe = Convert.ToDecimal(cells[4]);
                    opj.Juzgado = Convert.ToInt32(cells[5]);
                    opj.Liquidada = false;
                    opj.NroExpediente = Convert.ToInt32(cells[6]);
                    opj.NroFolio = Convert.ToInt32(cells[7]);
                    opj.Presentacion = Convert.ToDateTime(cells[8]);
                    opj.RetencionGan = Convert.ToDecimal(cells[9]);
                    opj.RetencionIva = Convert.ToDecimal(cells[10]);
                    _context.Opjs.Add(opj);
                }
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(content);

        }
        else
        {
            return Ok("ERROR");
        }

    }
```

**ACTUALIZACION 2**

@fredyfx Coloque un punto de interrupción para ver cuantas lineas me toma. En mi archivo de ejemplo solo tengo 2 filas, pero me procesa 512. Evidentemente estoy haciendo algo mal. La duda que me surge es si de esta forma es la mejor. Agrego imagen del punto de interrupción:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar todos los detalles? ¿Quieres ingresar ese archivo csv en un campo de la tabla de tu base de datos? ¿En qué momento haces conexión a tu bd y le mandas el CSV como parámetro y valor (archivo) para que sea procesado?

Comment: Gracias por responder, perdón por la poca explicación. Justo me estaba retirando de mi trabajo y me apagaban la luz. Exactamente, quiero ingresar ese archivo Csv a la tabla de la base de datos. No hice todavía ninguna conexión a la base de datos y mandar el archivo porque no lo pude hacer. Solo esta parte donde subo el archivo a un directorio temporal.

Comment: Coloca parte del archivo CSV :)

Comment: Puedes utilizar un framework para ayudarte con este tarea de CSV. Te recomiendo uno que utilizamos [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) que puedes ver como manipular [el formato CSV](http://docs.servicestack.net/csv-format) asi lo puedes parsear al texto y que no se tu impedimento, lo mapeas a un lista de objetos (y no estar luchando con separadores, fin de linea, etc) y desde la lista de objetos que mapeas lo utilizas para lo que necesitas (en tu caso guardar en la db)

Answer (score 0):

@jose-a-fernandez
Bueno creo que lo pude lograr. Instale muchos paquetes, pero no pude hacer que me leyeran el archivo (obvio que es por falta de entendimiento).

Seguí entonces con C# y lo que escribí es lo siguiente, que por el momento responde bastante bien. Faltan algunas validaciones pero probé con dos lineas y me inserto las dos.

```
            List<string> strContent = new List<string>(); //creo un List para almacenar los datos del archivo CSV

        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new StreamReader(files.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                while (!stream.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var linea = stream.ReadLine();
                    strContent.Add(linea);//agrego al List el contenido del archivo                   
                }           

                foreach(var item in strContent.Skip(1))//salteo las cabeceras
                {
                    var cells = item.Split(";");//separo por ;

                    opj.NroOrden = Convert.ToInt32(cells[0]);
                    opj.Abogado = cells[1];
                    opj.Caratula = cells[2];
                    opj.Dni = Convert.ToInt32(cells[3]);
                    opj.Importe = Convert.ToDecimal(cells[4]);
                    opj.Juzgado = Convert.ToInt32(cells[5]);
                    opj.Liquidada = false;
                    opj.NroExpediente = Convert.ToInt32(cells[6]);
                    opj.NroFolio = Convert.ToInt32(cells[7]);
                    opj.Presentacion = Convert.ToDateTime(cells[8]);
                    opj.RetencionGan = Convert.ToDecimal(cells[9]);
                    opj.RetencionIva = Convert.ToDecimal(cells[10]);

                    _context.Opjs.Add(opj);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
            return Ok("Éxito");//si llego aca esta todo bien

        }
        else
        {
            return Ok("ERROR");//no se cargo ningún archivo
        }
```

Si hay alguien que quiere corregir y decirme si es correcta la forma o si existe (me imagino que si) otra forma de hacerlo mas eficiente bienvenido sea.

Saludos.